# XSLT Transformation of Dates

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I'm struggling with XSLT to deal with a columns of dates where the data is a mix of dates and blanks. The data is exported from FileMaker, so I know the column types, and whilst (with help from elsewhere) I have been able to deal with currency formatting and applying formatted headings, I cannot get it to work for data where one or more date columns are present.
I've output some data to XML so it's apparent what I'm starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="01-09-2015" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="Server 13.0v9"/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="D/m/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="My_App.fmp12" RECORDS="528"     TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
<METADATA>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_ClientName" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_OracleCode" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_Company_Trustee" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_Lead_Consultant" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_TargetMarketOrganisation" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_Stock_Exchange" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_Status" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_LostTo" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_ReasonLost" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_DateLatestClientFirst" TYPE="DATE"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_ClientAtRisk" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_ClientAtRiskComment" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="d_Actions_Last_12_Months" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client_REVENUE__current::d_Revenue_Half_Year" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client_REVENUE__current::d_Revenue_Full_Year" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client_REVENUE__plus_1::d_Revenue_Half_Year" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client_REVENUE__plus_1::d_Revenue_Full_Year" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client_REVENUE__plus_2::d_Revenue_Half_Year" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client_REVENUE__plus_2::d_Revenue_Full_Year" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
</METADATA>
<RESULTSET FOUND="528">
<ROW MODID="3" RECORDID="1">
<COL><DATA>Record 1</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>616375</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Company</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Other, AN</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Yes</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Active</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>N</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>64911.25</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>28987.5</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>29143.75</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="3" RECORDID="2">
<COL><DATA>Record 2</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>603888</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Trustee</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Other, AN</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Yes</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Active</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>01/01/1900</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>Low risk</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>N</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>2363.23</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>4325</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>14660</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

Because some of the numerical data is formatted as currency, I have had to strip out any non-numeric characters during the transformation, but what I also wanted to do was to include dates as dates in my output, not as strings. Here is the XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"  
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"  
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"  
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"  
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"  
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">  
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>

<Workbook>
<!-- define the style for the heading row -->
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="Heading">
<Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" />
</Style>
</Styles>
<!-- set the worksheet name -->
<Worksheet ss:Name="DC_MG">
<Table>
<!-- populate and format the headings -->
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Client Name</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Project Code</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Company/Trustee</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Lead Consultant</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Target Market Organisation</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Stock Exchange</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Status</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Lost To</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Reason Lost</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Date Latest Client First</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Client At Risk</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Client At Risk Comment</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Actions Last 12 Months</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Half Year 2012</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Full Year 2012</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Half Year 2013</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Full Year 2013</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Half Year 2014</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
<Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Full Year 2014</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<!-- add the data to each subsequent row -->
<xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
<Row>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</Row>
</xsl:for-each>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
</xsl:template>
<!--called for every "COL" node in a "ROW"-->
<xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
<xsl:variable name="fmType" select="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD[$i]/@TYPE" />
<xsl:variable name="ssType">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$fmType='NUMBER'">Number</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$fmType='DATE'">Date</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>String</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="{$ssType}">
<xsl:variable name="d" select="fmp:DATA" />
<xsl:choose>
<!--clean up number fields-->
<xsl:when test="$fmType='NUMBER'">
<xsl:value-of select="translate($d,translate($d,'0123456789.',''),'')" />
</xsl:when>
<!--ignore blank dates-->
<xsl:when test="$fmType='DATE'">
<!--am stuck as to what goes HERE-->
</xsl:when>
<!--pass other types unchanged-->
<xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$d" /></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</Data>
</Cell>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'm seeing is that when I attempt to open the resulting file (post XSLT transformation), I get an Problem Loading from Excel and a link to a log file displays. That log file contains the same 7 lines of code for each record in the data (528 records):

```
XML ERROR in Table  
REASON: Bad Value  
FILE:   C:\Users\ABC123DEF\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\84E8567E.xls  
GROUP:  Cell  
TAG:    Data  
ATTRIB: Type  
VALUE:  Date
```

So it doesn't seem to like the dates irrespective of whether they are valid or not. I could strip out the line:

```
<xsl:when test="$fmType='DATE'">Date</xsl:when>
```

But then all my dates would be strings.

I've run it through an online transformation tool (using my XSLT) and it gives me the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Styles>
      <Style ss:ID="Heading">
         <Font ss:Bold="1" ss:Size="10" />
      </Style>
   </Styles>
   <Worksheet ss:Name="DC_MG">
      <Table>
         <Row>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Client Name</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Project Code</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Company/Trustee</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Lead Consultant</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Target Market Organisation</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Stock Exchange</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Status</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Lost To</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Reason Lost</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Date Latest Client First</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Client At Risk</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Client At Risk Comment</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Actions Last 12 Months</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Half Year 2012</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Full Year 2012</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Half Year 2013</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Full Year 2013</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Half Year 2014</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="Heading">
               <Data ss:Type="String">Revenue Full Year 2014</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
         <Row>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Record 1</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">616375</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Company</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Other, AN</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Yes</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Date" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">N</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">64911.25</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">28987.5</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">29143.75</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
         <Row>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Record 2</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">603888</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Trustee</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Other, AN</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Yes</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Date">01/01/1900</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">Low risk</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">N</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">2363.23</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">4325</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number" />
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">14660</Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
      </Table>
   </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

But again, I still get the Problems Loading, and the same errors in the log file.
Any help/advice gratefully received.
Thanks
Martin

Comment: `<!--am stuck as to what goes HERE-->` if this question is to be about XSLT, then you need to know what is the intended result of the transformation (as XML code). Otherwise this will be a question about Excel. -- BTW, I don't see that your numbers have currency formatting, so I am not sure why they need to be processed. In any case, you could control this, as well as the date format, when you export from Filemaker.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. The intended result is that the dates/blanks are formatted as dates in Excel. I'm trying to avoid having to change my layouts in FileMaker as the date formats vary. I was suggested to look at doing the manipulation in the XSLT rather than changing the data source. The export is being saved as an Excel file, but I am unable to open the file at present due to the errors.

Comment: "*The intended result is that the dates/blanks are formatted as dates in Excel.*" I am not knowledgeable about Excel. Before I can help you with the XSLT part, one of us will have to find out what the XML result of this transformation (and the result of this transformation **is** XML code) needs to look like in order for Excel to accept it.

Comment: "*I'm trying to avoid having to change my layouts in FileMaker as the date formats vary.*" Keep in mind that the XSLT you produce will expect a certain date format as the input. That is unless you can be absolutely certain that a custom format is *not* being used in the export - in which case you may consult the DATABASE/@DATEFORMAT property in order to determine how the input is structured, before taking it apart and re-assembling it for the output. And that's not going to be simple.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. From the XML (in my original post), the DATEFORMAT is <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="D/m/yyyy", although this is not the same as the date format used in the respective FileMaker layouts (DD mmm YYYY). The dates appear to be coming through as dd/MM/YYYY (or blank), although am not sure if this has any bearing on the errors I'm seeing.

Comment: No, it hasn't - and this is not going to move forward until you find out exactly what Excel wants. I suspect it may be `YYYY-MM-DD` or perhaps `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: For reference, I've run the XML through the XSLT using an online tool, and whilst the transformed code looks fine (to my untrained eye) it will not open in Excel due to the same error in my original post (for both Date items). I've edited my original post to include the transformed XML.

Comment: I know what what your transformed code looks like. I don't know what it *should* look like.

Comment: It should look like a defined selection of columns with a row of bold headings at the top in a named worksheet. And for the reports where there are no date columns in the results, it works without any issue. I'm obviously not understanding what you need from me, so apologies.

Comment: "*I'm obviously not understanding what you need from me*" I am afraid that is so. Look, in your transformed XML, you have this: `<Data ss:Type="Date">01/01/1900</Data>`. It probably needs to be `<Data ss:Type="Date">1990-01-01</Data>`. Or perhaps `<Data ss:Type="Date">1990-01-01T00:00:00</Data>`. You need to consult MS documentation and find out (or experiment, if you're feeling adventurous).